# Flutter app is closing when sending request using Dio with huge data

Tags: flutter, dio

I am trying to send a huge image using *FormData* and *Dio*, the server side is written in *NodeJS*

Whenever I send an image for let's say **1 MB** and less it's working perfectly, but I've tried to send an image with **17 MB** size the application lagged for a while, then exited

here's the flutter code

```
Future<Uint8List> _convertImageToUint8List(final String imagePath) async {
    ByteData imageByteDate = await rootBundle.load(imagePath);
    ByteBuffer imageBuffer = imageByteDate.buffer;
    return imageBuffer.asUint8List();
  }

  void _testUploadingImageWithDio(
      {final String ip,
      final String port,
      final String api,
      final String imagePath}) async {
    Dio dio = new Dio();
    Uint8List imageUint8List = await _convertImageToUint8List(imagePath);
    FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
      'image': imageUint8List,
    });
    String url = 'http://$ip:$port/$api';
    print('URL: $url}');
    var response = await dio.post(url, data: formData);
    print('response: $response');
  }
```

As well as I've tried another class in flutter **MultipartRequest**, but the image was doubled in its size, I mean the image with **17 MB** reached the server with size **32 MB** and the image was corrupted.

Here's the code

```
void _testUploadingImageWithMultiPartRequest(
      {final String ip,
      final String port,
      final String api,
      final String imagePath}) async {
    // Constructing the request
    Uri postUri = Uri.parse('http://$ip:$port/$api');
    print('URI ${postUri.toString()}');
    http.MultipartRequest request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", postUri);
    // request.fields['user'] = 'someone@somewhere.com';

    // Loading the image from image path using root bundle
    // convert it to buffer and uint8 list
    // append it to the request
    Uint8List imageUint8List = await _convertImageToUint8List(imagePath);
    http.MultipartFile imageToBeSent = new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        'image', imageUint8List,
        contentType: new MediaType('image', 'png'));
    request.files.add(imageToBeSent);

    // Sending the request
    request.send().then((response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) print("Uploaded!");
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print(onError);
    });
  }
```

For server side application I am doing the following

```
const upload = multer({storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter, limits: {fieldSize: 200 * 1024 * 1024}});
app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    const buffer = Buffer.from(req.body['image']);
    fs.writeFileSync('./some_image', buffer);
    try {
        return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'File uploded successfully'
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

#### Edit

For the 17 MB image

[image: First big image hex code]

For the corrupted one, on server side

[image: Corrupted image on server side]

For a small image which works fine

[image: Second image hex code]

Comment: what is magic number of sent and receives files (i mean first 8-16 bytes in hex)?

Comment: @pskink There's no magic or specific number, only trying one image with different sizes

Comment: what are the first 8-16 bytes of both files (in [hexidecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal))?

Comment: @pskink How do I get them, by logging the buffer ?

Comment: you have both files on the filesystem, right? if so use any binary editor to check their first 8-16 bytes

Comment: and the received file? that one with 34 MB

Comment: you are not saving your file as a binary data - it is somehow encoded (utf encoding or something...)

Comment: @pskink Yes, you're right I changed the encoding to binary and for multipart request now the files are in the same size as they've been sent but still when I change the extension of the image it's corrupted, and the Dio is stucking and not working

Answer (score 0):

Is this server config related?

For example, for Nginx has a config: client_max_body_size 50M;